# What is the meaning of kai/かい?

Tags: translation, meaning

Here is the context it was used in: 
"また来たのかい？"

What does かい mean here? Is it a suffix?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Japanese Stack Exchange! These could be related to your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2864/in-what-situation-can-i-use-かい-for-interrogative-question, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15723/sentence-question-ending-かい-how-is-it-different-from-just-か.

Comment: Hi user35923, thanks for your first question on Japanese Language Stack Exchange. If possible, please could you indicate your research effort in your question? This makes it easier for other members of the community to answer your question in a way that is helpful to you. It also makes it less of a translation question, which is off-topic for the site (see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your comments/answers!