# Adding -い at the end of questions

Tags: meaning, usage

どうしたんだ　vs　どうしたんだい

そうか　vs　そうかい

This kind of thing. Is it a formality difference? Is it dialectical/Regional? Age related?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15770/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16116/9831

Answer (score 1):

The i at the end is a shortened form of yo
Sou kai = sou ka yo.
Doushita ndai = doushita nda yo.

Its slang.

Comment: Interesting theory; do you have any source on that?

Comment: https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/kai-question-particle.html. in Wikipedia tho, kai is its own particle. But the link suggests its origin came from the ka-yo particles

Comment: That theory doesn't have consensus, and apart from etymology, it's not interchangeable to current "yo".

Comment: Yeah, this answer seems to imply that hey can be used interchangeably.