# Use of せんかい in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

The line reads

> 一礼せんかい

The translation should be something like "where is your bow?" or "you should/must bow" but I have never seen **せんかい** used in that way before. The only thing I can possibly think of is that  せんかい is **千回** and is actually emphasizing the importance of the bow but just wanted to check if there's something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a western dialect. In Kansai-ben it is pronounced せんかい【HHHL】. せんかえ【HHHL】 is another variant. In standard Japanese it would correspond to しないか【LHLL】 with a strong demanding tone, and it basically means しろ（よ）.

This かい is different from the かい in the question linked from the other answer, which is used to soften a question.

---

Some standard Japanese speakers, particularly men of a certain age or above, might say せんか【HLL】.

Answer (score 1):

せんかい here is actually せん (= しない in dialect) + [sentence final かい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2864/in-what-situation-can-i-use-%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84-for-interrogative-question), and so the intended interpretation is "Aren't you going to give a bow?" as you surmised.

Comment: This せんかい basically means しろよ. Doesn't your translation sound too soft for that? Or can you say it as an indirect order?

Comment: In standard Japanese it would be しないか, not しないかい.

Comment: In my variety of English at least, my translation can have a mocking tone (which I thought fit the situation).

Comment: I see, but in my variety of Japanese せんかい has a direct and pretty strong tone.